# Limit Set of All Real Numbers

Tags: real-analysis

Not even sure how to start this one. Does anyone know how to do this?

Prove that there exists a sequence such that its limit set is the set
of all real numbers

Limit set is the set of all subsequence limits btw

Comment: List the rationals as $r_0,r_1,\dots$. This can be done since there are countably many rationals.

Comment: @André Nicolas: Great minds think alike--simultaneously , it seems.

Comment: Well, I erased my comment as Andre's is easier.  But I might as well put it:  I was thinking of $f(t) = t \sin(t)$, and then the sequence is $\{f(t_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where $t_n = \sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$.  The only tricky part is showing that, even though $|f'(t)|$ grows, it grows slowly enough so that the difference between sequence values $|f(t_{n+1})-f(t_n)|$ still gets smaller and smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerate all the Rational numbers in the Real line, and you have your sequence.

We have that the Rationals are dense in the Reals, which implies that every irrational is the limit of a sequence of Rationals. Specifically, consider any irrational $a:=a_0.a_1a_2...a_n....$, then the Rational number $b:=a_0.a_1...a_k00000...$ approximates  $a$ as well as you want by taking as many terms in the expansion as you need. Then $$|a-b|=0.000000a_{k+1}a_{k+2}..... < \frac{9}{10^{k+2}} \rightarrow 0$$ as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: wound't this be the limit set with all rational numbers (instead of the limit set with all reals)?

Comment: But the Rationals are dense in the Reals, which implies that every irrational is the limit of a sequence of Rationals. Specifically, consider any irrational $a:=a_0.a_1a_2...a_n....$, then the Rational number $b:=a_0.a_1...a_k00000... $approximates  $a$ as well as you want by taking as many terms in the expansion as you need.

Answer (score 1):

Start the sequence with $0$.

Then write $-1,1$.

Then write $-\frac{4}{2},-\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{4}{2}$.

Then write $-\frac{16}{4},-\frac{15}{4}, -\frac{13}{4},\dots, -\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4},\dots, \frac{16}{4}$.

Then write $-\frac{64}{8}, \frac{63}{8},\dots, \frac{63}{8},\frac{64}{8}$, skipping $\frac{0}{8}$, though it really doesn't matter.

Then write everything from $-\frac{256}{16}$ to $\frac{256}{16}$, in steps of $\frac{1}{16}$, skipping \frac{0}{16}$.

Continue.